# Group by concatenate unique string only in Excel Pivot table or Power query

Tags: excel, powerquery, powerpivot

I have table and output desired like this:
[I have tried the formula Concatnatex](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7OKwb.png)

I had tried this function: =CONCATENATEX(Table1,[sender name]," , ") in Pivot table. But it also including duplicate value from sender name. Can we add distinct somehow in this formula?

I want each value at to be considered once in concatenated column against the parent column.

Thanks in advance.

Kulchandra

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
=CONCATENATEX(VALUES(Table1[sender name]),Table1[sender name]," , ")
```